# storybook won't run on localhost

Tags: storybook

I'm running Storybook 6.1.21.  At some point it stopped loading on localhost:6006.  On localhost it loads a white page in the browser and logs this to the console:

`GET http://localhost:6006/main.daf8ed0c474096531109.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

If I open Storybook on http://192.168.86.137:6006 it works fine.

I'm at at loss for how to troubleshoot this, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

So something else is running on :6006, I'm not sure what it is yet, but it's not loading correctly.  If I change storybook to run on a different port it starts on localhost without a problem:

`start-storybook -p 6007`

Comment: On Linux, try `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to determine if "node" or anything else is listening on this port

Answer (score 5):

Empty cache and hard reload resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Yep, deleting node_modules/.cache fixed it.

Comment: I was missing the addon console of storybook until I deleted my browser cache...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody experiences the same problem with laravel sail or some docker environment in general.
After installing storybook you have to map the port in the docker-compose.yml file. Add this to you docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  laravel.test:
    ports:
      - '6006:6006'
```

Comment: Thanks! Make sure you restart the container to map the new port bindings or you'll still hit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json script add the following...

- Prefix with `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`
- Add `-no-manager-cache` to parameters

```
"storybook": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider start-storybook -p -no-manager-cache 6006",
```

Found this solution [here](https://graphicscove.com/how-to-fix-cannot-get-when-running-storybook)